# How to get current url in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I created a product-based service website. I need my customer to get quotes from the website to my WhatsApp.

Example:

```
<button> 
    <a href=" https://api.whatsapp.com/send? phone=whatsappnumber&text=The current URL of the website... I need a quote for this product" >
    Send a quote on WhatsApp
</button>
```

How to get the current URL of the website? Please assist me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the current URL with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-the-current-url-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

The `window.location` object can be used to get the current page address (URL) and to redirect the browser to a new page.

1. `window.location.href` returns the href (URL) of the current page

```js
console.log(window.location.href)
```

2. `window.location.hostname` returns the domain name of the web host

```js
console.log(window.location.hostname)
```

3. `window.location.pathname` returns the path and filename of the current page

```js
console.log(window.location.pathname)
```

4. `window.location.protocol` returns the web protocol used (http: or https:)

```js
console.log(window.location.protocol)
```

5. `window.location.assign()` loads a new document

```js
function newDoc() {
  window.location.assign("https://stackoverflow.com")
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Learn More" onclick="newDoc()">
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the current URL of the website, you can use the `window.location.href` property in JavaScript. You can then add this value to the text parameter in the WhatsApp link as follows:

```
<button>
  <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=whatsappnumber&text='I need a quote for this product' + window.location.href">
    Send a quote on WhatsApp
  </a>
</button>
```

This will send a message to your WhatsApp number with the text "I need a quote for this product" followed by the current URL of the website.

Answer (score 0):

This would work without an anchor tag.

```
<button onclick="window.open('https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=whatsappnumber&text=' + window.location.href, '_blank');">Send a quote on whatsapp</button>
```