# qts on javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Request Address in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029387/request-address-in-javascript)

Is there any method to retrieve the URL of the current page in JavaScript or jquery?

Please help.

Comment: Please choose suitable titles for your question.

Answer (score 2):

[`window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties)

Here is how you would do it in jQuery :P

```
(function($) {
   $.getUrl = function() {
       return window.location.href;
   }
})(jQuery);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/JCt73/).

<sup>**Warning**: Obviously the jQuery function is for LOLs. Don't really use it.</sup>

Comment: @Blender I added some :)

Comment: made an overkill jQuery solution: `$.getUrl()`. That code inits the function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `location.href`

```
alert(location.href)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

document.location.href

Answer (score 0):

Use the

```
document.location.href
```