# Javascript to determine what page I'm on

Tags: javascript

So I have an image which displays on every page, however I'd like to write a script that will, depending on the page, replace the image with another image. How would I programmatically determine what page I am on? The actual image replacement I can already do.

Comment: Why the -1? I figure it's an acceptable question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Request Address in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029387/request-address-in-javascript)

Comment: I downvoted because the question shows no original research effort (per tooltip on downvote arrow). And two others downvoted for some reason. Mystery 1/3 solved.

Comment: Alright, in the future I'll make sure to show a better effort of the research I've done prior to asking the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `location`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert(window.location);
   // and you can set the location to move to another page
   window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com"
</script>
```

Comment: Was intending on it, just had to wait for the time period to expire.