# Get current webpage URL

Tags: javascript, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Request Address in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029387/request-address-in-javascript)

I am using a Facebook plugin in my web page, as shown:

```
<iframe 
   src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOUR_URL"
   scrolling="no" 
   frameborder="0"
   style="border:none; width:120px; height:30px">
</iframe>
```

How can I get the current URL of the web page, using JavaScript? I need to assign current URL instead of `href=YOUR_URL`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't put an `href` parameter. Facebook will default to the current page.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
window.location.href (or simply location.href)
```

[Definition](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp) of location.href

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is your friend here:

```
var original = $("iframe").attr('src');
var url = window.location;
$("iframe").attr('src', original + url);​
```

HTML

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href="></iframe>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/2JEay/