# Is there a way I can include the current webpage url?

Tags: url, html

I have a webpage that I want people to fill information out on and then a response emailed to me with that information. Is there a way that I can include the url in the email from that page using html?

I have no clue how to start this. I saw a similar question here: [Get current webpage URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224957/get-current-webpage-url)

but I don't understand how to turn the src: url to the one of the page I am currently on. It seems like I should be able to reference it, but I am unsure how.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using javascript?

Comment: Show your current code. How are you sending the email?

Comment: no, its in a program that won't allow me to use jscript. I can only use html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with straight html. You can use Javascript to change the `src` attribute:

```
document.getElementById("myElement").setAttribute("src", window.location.href);
```

In this example, it's assumed that you are attempting to change the `src` attribute of an element with the `id` "`myElement`".

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript) question. To get the webpage URL with JavaScript, you can use `document.URL`. You can then use it for what you want.