# Copy current url into form text box using Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

Would like to copy the current url into a text box and create a prompt before it

I have class assigned to the text box in the form

Is there a way to use something close to the following to make this work?

```
$('.txtbox').val(window.location.pathname);
```

Thanks

Comment: [Request Address in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029387/request-address-in-javascript?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('.txtbox').val(window.location.href);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to take - do I need to account for the value="" to make it pre-fill correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It is working well for me. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jimp/5jRVU/ Are you possibly trying to execute that script before the <input/> exists in the page?